# Seperate all types of videos into frames(series of images)

Tags: java, video, image-processing

> Hi I am working on **image processing** where I need to **convert all types**
>   of **videos into series of frames**.
>
> I already **tried with JCodec** which **worked only with .mp4 type videos**.
>
> **Below code** shows what I did before to grab frames from video,

```
 try {
                    int frameNumber = 0;
                    BufferedImage frame = null;
                    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                    {   
                        frameNumber = i;

                    //video from which frames can be retrieved, declare frame number,
                    //returns numbered frame from video 

                    frame = FrameGrab.getFrame(new File("D:\\Traffic.mp4\\"), frameNumber);

                    //write frame as image declare image format and file path where image
                    //is to be write

                    ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("D:\\Frames2\\frame_"+frameNumber+".png\\"));
                }
                System.out.println("Finished");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

> Here in above code I am trying to **read Traffic.mp4 video** and getting
>   first 100 frames. This **code is working fine for all types of .mp4**
>   videos, but as I tried with **.flv, .avi type of video it is giving**
>   me **NullPointer exception**.
>
> So is there **any other Java API** I can try which accepts all type of
>   videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/), a  wrapper of FFMpeg for java. FFMpeg has support for processing individual frames so I guess Xuggler won't be far from it, the demo [DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java) seems to be doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/). It uses JavaCV as an interface to cameras and media files. Check this [Example](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/examples/mediaFile.html) showing how to get each video frame from a WMV file for image processing purpose.

In the JavaCV group there is a [Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacv/8xdbPFZHDgo) about supported file formats.

Comment: @Gabrial thanks for help...But I unable to run program...because it first given me jar exceptions I downloaded almost 3 to 4 jar, then now it is giving me "no jniopencv_core in java.library.path" exception....so can you please provide me all other jar or dll files required.

Comment: As I said, Marvin uses JavaCV, therefore you need to install OpenCV and JavaCV properly. Take a look at the following posts:
http://anshulkatta.blogspot.in/2013/04/setup-javacv-in-windows.html   http://anshulkatta.blogspot.in/2013/04/using-javacv-in-marvinframework.html

 If the problem persists, contact me by e-mail.